# Meteor: Retrieving user's records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am working on meteor project(0.8.2) and  have got a "addressDB" Collection with {name, address} as fields. When i try to retrieve the records of "addressDB" collection. It gives proper results using: addressDB.find({});  But I need to get only the records of the user who logged in meteor app. But after logging in it gives all records. 
My html code:

```
<div class="newCenters">
     New records given are:<br>
     {{#each entries}}
     <strong>Added By: {{user.username}}</strong><br>
     <strong> Address: </strong><i>{{address}}</i><br>
     {{/each}}
</div>
```

My js code is:

```
Template.entries.entries = function () {
   // return all entries sorted by time
  return addressDB.find({}, { sort: { time: -1 }});// I assume change is required here
    }
```

and i'm inserting data in this code:

```
var user = Meteor.user();
             if (!user) {
                 return;
             }
addressDB.insert({ 
user:user,// this inserts logged user's username
address:temp});
console.log("data inserted");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a selector to indicate which records you want. Because you are storing the whole user object, you will need to match the user's id to `user._id` in your `addressDB` documents. The current user id can be found with `Meteor.userId()`. Putting all this together gives us:

```js
return addressDB.find({'user._id': Meteor.userId()}, {sort: { time: -1 }});
```

I suspect that will solve your immediate need, however I wouldn't recommend storing the whole user object when you initialize your data. It will end up storing things like the user's profile, username, etc. when all you need is the id. Instead, I would just do this:

```js
var userId = Meteor.userId();

if (!userId)
  return;

addressDB.insert({userId: userId, address:temp});
```

And then your template query could look like:

```js
return addressDB.find({userId: Meteor.userId()}, {sort: { time: -1 }});
```